# how can i select rows by unique index list created with multi columns

Tags: mysql

I have a  unique index in table t, that is:
    UNIQUE KEY `idx_abc` (`cola`, `colb`, `colc`)

and I want a sql like:

```
SELECT * FROM T WHERE (`cola`, `colb`, `colc`) IN
{
  (1,1,1),
  (2,2,2),
  (3,3,3),
  ...
}
```

Comment: Please show table t with example data and your expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this:

```
SELECT * FROM T WHERE (`cola`, `colb`, `colc`) IN
(
  (1,1,1),
  (2,2,2),
  (3,3,3),
  ...
)
```